# full offline package of visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, offline

I want one complete offline package of 'visual studio enterprise 2015 update 1' that includes UWP tools(SDk,emulators) for full installation on multiple machines that are not connected to internet.

So what all steps I need to follow to create one complete offline package.

Please help me and provide me details of steps.

Comment: Can you just not download the ISO fro MSDN and burn a DVD from it

Comment: but that iso does not include UWA tools like windows SDK, emulators etc.. It's size is 5.89 GB. I want full package

Answer (score 0):

Please see the instructions for creating your own offline installer (that is more complete than the ISO that VS ships) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#BKMK_Offline

Comment: thanks.. But i tried that one and disappointed because although using layout switch it downloaded approx. 11 GB package but doesn't install emulators. I want one complete offline package

Comment: @RajatTiwari - what happens when you launch vs_enterprise.exe from the folder where you told /layout to store everything? Do you see the universal application tools in setup's custom tree view? And have you checked the checkbox next to the sub-entry that says Windows <some version> emulator? Your scenario is exactly what the layout functionality was built for, so I can't say what went wrong from this description. And last, I'm answering from my phone, so my names are not precise matches for the labels in the real UI. I hope they're close enough for you to understand what I mean.

Comment: when we use /layout switch then it only ask for download location. It doesn't show setup's custom tree view from which we can select desired tools. it starts downloading automatically when we click download button.

Comment: @RajatTiwari - after that download finishes, you can take that folder (in its many GB entirety) to an offline machine and run vs_enterptise.exe in the top folder. Then, setup will use the downloaded installers in sub folders, including emulators.

Comment: I had done exactly that and all components are installed but emulators failed to install..

Comment: @RajatTiwari - dos the emulator installer give any kind of an error message? Failing to install is different than not being available to install offline, and all along, I thought we were only talking about being available offline. If the installer ran but failed, I'd have to know what error message happened, and likely, I'd even need detailed logs to really diagnose. Can you tell me what the error message is, and I'll help once I know loosely what is failing?

Comment: after offline setup is completed i got the following error message--------- Emulators for Windows 10 mobile : The installer failed. There was a problem downloading your product. Error code: 15605

Comment: @RajatTiwari - that sounds unexpected given that you were running from a layout folder. I'm afraid that I'll have to get somebody from the emulator team to tell us how to further diagnose this issue. The biggest challenge there is that most Microsoft folks are out of the office until January 4th (including me). If that's too long, let me know and I'll see if I can find an engineer who is working some during the next two weeks to dig in further.

Comment: thanks a lot for response. Please solve my problem as soon as possible. one week already passed when i got the problem.

Comment: @RajatTiwari - sorry for the delay. What you're describing is not the normal path for an offline install, so the next step is to examine the log files from your machine in   %temp%\emulator   Would you be willing to zip those files up and share them with me? You can reach me directly at eric.knox@microsoft.com. From there, I'll get an engineer who owns the emulator installer to investigate and advise you.

Comment: Thanks for reply... But i don't have any log files as i had cleaned my temp folder. Forget about the all previous errors now I am ready to download again the full offline setup of visual studio 2015 with UWP tools(sdk,emulator etc.). So provide me all detailed steps from the start to end by which i get full offline package.

Comment: The URL I replied with above in my answer has the set of steps to take. My team has followed those steps many times to validate the scenario. But if you encounter any errors after executing them, please let me know and I'll see if I can help figure out what happened on your machine that is not happening in my testing environment.

Comment: I had downloaded the full offline package (11.3GB) again by using /layout switch of web installer but it also fails with same error. full visual studio installed but emulators are not installed. now please provide me or share a link from where I can download full package. Is size specified above is correct size of offline package or it is not fully downloaded?. please help i am tired by all these.....

Comment: @RajatTiwari - I'm sorry my earlier answer wasn't clear. The error code you referenced means that the installer was downloaded and present but failed for some other reason. I'm not surprised that downloading it again produced the same error because something else must be happening on your machine. I'm still willing to give you more specific guidance if you can zip up your  %temp%\emulator  folder and share it with me via email at eric.knox@microsoft.com. But until I can see what the specific error is, I won't know how to recommend a fix.

Comment: I had sent you an email 2-3 days ago but i didn't got any reply. Have you received it or not?

Comment: Sorry Rajat - I did get the email, but I lost track of it among my other ongoing work. I have just finished sending a reply with what my team found out and some next step ideas via email.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any solution for offline install UWP Tools 
except Google supports VS2015 Then Everything will be easy and ready to download just like android development tools

Comment: for years i was thinking about why android is so popular but windows mobile not !!! if i decide to develop an app for Windows Mobile its so hard for me to prepare requirements tool !!!! then if i decide to develop an app for android its so easy to download tools and start developing !!!!!!